# how to get verify if user is already registered

Tags: php, mysql

Guys, I am new in PHP and nowadays am working on android application and in this application I have connected my app with PHP MySQL DB and everything is working fine but the problem is now I want to check if user cnic no is available  in DB so query give me to return back if no so it will be inserted in DB please help me i will be really thankful to you all of the guys 
    Thanks

```
<?php
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($HostName, $HostUser, $HostPass, $DatabaseName);
 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
 {
 $DefaultId = 0;

 $ImageData = $_POST['image_path'];

 $ImageName = $_POST['image_name'];

 $Fullname = $_POST['fullname'];

 $CNIC = $_POST['cnic'];

  $Mobile = $_POST['mobile'];

  $Address = $_POST['address'];

   $District = $_POST['district'];

   $Gender = $_POST['gender'];

   $Education = $_POST['education'];

   $Ward = $_POST['ward'];

   $Ps = $_POST['ps'];

   $Uc = $_POST['uc'];

   $Bjf = $_POST['bjf'];

   $By = $_POST['by'];

   $Dt = $_POST['dt'];

   $Email = $_POST['email'];

 $GetOldIdSQL ="SELECT id FROM information ORDER BY id ASC";

 $Query = mysqli_query($conn,$GetOldIdSQL);

 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($Query)){

 $DefaultId = $row['id'];
 }

 $ImagePath = "images/$DefaultId.png";

 $ServerURL = "laserlightskincare.com/$ImagePath";

 //$InsertSQL = "insert into information (image_path,image_name,Fullname,CNIC,mobile,Address,District,ps,uc,ward,Gender,education,Doj,bjf,boy) values ('$ServerURL','$ImageName','$Fullname','$Cnic','$Mobile','$Address','$District','$PS','$UC','Ward','$Gender','Education','$Doj','$bjf','$boj','$boy')";
 $InsertSQL = "insert into information (image_path,image_name,Fullname,CNIC,mobile,Address,District,Gender,education,ward,ps,uc,bjf,boy,Doj,email) values ('$ServerURL','$ImageName','$Fullname','$CNIC','$Mobile','$Address','$District','$Gender','$Education','$Ward','$Ps','$Uc','$Bjf','$By','$Dt','$Email')";

 if(mysqli_query($conn, $InsertSQL)){

 file_put_contents($ImagePath,base64_decode($ImageData));

 echo "You have successfully registered";
 } 
 mysqli_close($conn);
 }else{
 echo "Not Uploaded";
 }

?>
```

Comment: What is your User CNIC number for?

Comment: sir this just a field of cnic I don't know how to write query please update my code i will be really thankful to you

Comment: To verify if a user exist using any value you want (which need be unique for each user such as email address or mobile number), you have to make a select query and search for that unique value in the database, if the return value (rows number) is one, the user already exist, if it's zero, the user doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before the insert query; make a select query and check if the result is empty or not, 
Another solution is to make a unique index for cnic  information table so you can not insert a new record

Comment: can i make current column of my db is unique like cnic column

Answer (score 2):

First store your **cnic** value in an **array** using `select` statement and `for()` loop.

Then using the `if()` condition **compare** the **cnic** value in your db with the **cnic** value inserted. If the value is found then print that the **cnic** is used once else **insert** the data using your `insert` query.

Hope this helps you.

**NOTE :**
You should use some more appropriate value then the **cnic** value to check if the data is there in the db or not. I would suggest you compare the **email addresses or mobile numbers** of the users as they are unique for each user who signs up entering their email address and mobile number and **it cannot be used again** for the signup process.